# ROUND in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Please tell me why the following code:

```
round((CASE WHEN x.sprd_units = 0 then 0 ELSE sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN d.unit_qty ELSE 0 END) / x.sprd_units)::numeric, 2) as space_units,
```

returns error:syntax error at or near ")"
and how the proper syntax should look like
(PostgreSql 8.3)
thanks

Comment: plz show us full query once.....

Comment: and also which ')' it marks as the syntax error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is that you have 2 usages of CASE but you only END once.
Also, I rather use `CAST` then `::numeric` as it is a little more database-agnostic so I replaced that.

Try this;

```
round(CAST(CASE WHEN x.sprd_units = 0 then 0 ELSE sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICIAL PROJECTION' THEN d.unit_qty ELSE 0 END) / x.sprd_units END as numeric), 2) as space_units
```